# Using preg_match_all need regex looking for double forward slash

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am using the following code to find jpg images with https in the URL.

```
preg_match_all('#\bhttps://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/)).jpg#', $data, $images);
```

At the moment this returns all jpg image URLs but requires https in the string.

I would like to use // (double forward slash) instead of https.

Something like this; but of course it was not that simple haha

```
preg_match_all('#\b//[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/)).jpg#', $data, $images);
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Probably want to get rid of the word boundary `\b` but you can make the `s` optional `'#\bhttp(s)?://`

Comment: The issue here is that I am scraping data that does not use http or https as a delimeter, the image code is something like <img src="//cdn.example.com/image.jpg" ...> and not always cdn.example.com so need to target //

Comment: Why not simply: `preg_match_all('#//\S+?\.jpg#', $data, $images);`

Answer (score 0):

The following was the working regex `'/\/\/\S+?\.jpg/'` I went with.

```
preg_match_all('/\/\/\S+?\.jpg/', $data, $images);
```

Thanks Toto in comments for a hint pointing me in the right direction!